Strange capacitor in Murata BNX filter
I've torn apart an EMI filter from Murata (BNX022-01). Does anyone have any idea what type of capacitor is this?

Judging from a datasheet (https://www.murata.com/en-us/api/pdfdownloadapi?cate=&partno=BNX022-01%23),

it's a capacitor (also why is it drawn like that?), but I don't understand its structure. The capacitor's material crumbled easily when I tore it apart:

And its outer surface seems to be metallized.

Hi there -- what is the source for the figure (citation and link)? Correct attribution is required for all external sources here.

1st and 3rd pics are mine, and 2nd is from official datasheet from Murata

At first glance I thought that the mfg might have wanted to indicate that the capacitor had CB connection as one of the "plates". Then I thought it could be a "feed-through capacitor" but there must have been another line in the symbol.

I also found alternative version of datasheet for BNX 002-01, another filter from the same series (https://docs.rs-online.com/d10a/0900766b813f32b2.pdf, 1st page), and there are,in fact, words "feed-through-capacitor". I still don't understand it though

According to Murata catalog for the BNX series filters, it's a "through-type barrier layer capacitor".
It's basically a SMD capacitor.
Instead of just putting a standard capacitor with two terminals to signal and ground on a PCB, the signal is simply passed through the capacitor for better filtering. They are also called feed-thru capacitors.

Thanks! If I understood correctly, one of the other reasons to use feed-through caps is when the current is high (several amps)?

Also, is a feed-through cap the same in terms of modeling as an ordinary cap (for example, in AWR Microwave Office)?

No, the feedthru cap is not used due to high current. It is used to have shortest possible capacitor leads between filtered signal/supply and ground to minimize the lead inductance. Yes a feedthru capacitor is "just" an ordinary capacitor. For some definition of ordinary. You don't know the parameters of the capacitor, except it's a 1uF 15% 50V. You are just given the parameters of the whole filter.
